# Using EXEC() or SP_EXECUTESQL with SQL Common Table Expressions

Tags: sql-server, exec, common-table-expression, sp-executesql

How do I use EXEC(@SQL) or EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL(@SQL) with Common Table Expressions?

Below does not work.

```
WITH CTE_Customer (ID,  Name)
AS
(
    EXEC (@strSqlCommand)
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that you cant:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx says:
"The CTE_query_definition must meet the same requirements as for creating a view"
Which basically says that you're restricted to SELECT statements only.

Some workarounds might include using temp tables or table variables, but it really depends on context.

Comment: Thanks. Will try to use table variables.